# Azure DocumentDB with MongoDb protocol does not support $lookup aggregate

Tags: mongodb, azure

I have a Azure DocumentDB created with MongoDB protocol, while trying aggregate command just get following response:

```
assert: command failed: {
    "_t" : "OKMongoResponse",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 115,
    "errmsg" : "'$lookup' is not supported",
    "$err" : "'$lookup' is not supported"
}-
```

Comment: $lookup was introduced in mongodb 3.2. Which version of Mongodb are you using?

Comment: I'm not so sure which version, and where to config that? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-protocol-mongodb

Comment: db.version() command return "3.2.0"

Comment: $geoNear is not support too

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I m getting same error.